# Cognos Analytics 11 - Age groups

Tags: cognos, cognos-11

I have a data element expression I want to use as a category for a crosstable.

This gives me the errors "QE-DEF-0459 CCLException" and "QE-DEF-0261 QFWP", although I have followed the syntax properly. Any ideas what is causing this? It seems to be related to the [BIRTHDATE] column inside the when-clauses.

The error message goes like this: qe-def-0260 parsing error before or near position: 40 in: "case when (_years_between(current_date,"

The source database is Oracle.

Comment: Do you know what the data type is of [BIRTHDATE], timestamp, datetime, time?

Comment: Should be datetime

Answer (score 1):

Usually there are messages which are appended after the error number. The message should be helpful in solving your problem, so reading it would be helpful for you and including the text, rather than just quoting an error number when you ask for assistance could be helpful to others.

I'm not familiar with any case function in Cognos where the query item is required after the case.

Also Case requires an end operator.

Re-write your expression to be something like this, where I've removed birthdate and added the end.

```
case 
when (_years_between(current_date, [BIRTHDATE])>=0 and _years_between(current_date, [BIRTHDATE])<=49) then '0-49'
when (_years_between(current_date, [BIRTHDATE])>=50 and _years_between(current_date, [BIRTHDATE])<=100) then '50-100' 
else 'null'
end
```

[image]

Comment: Tried that alternative, with no success. The error message goes like this: qe-def-0260 parsing error before or near position: 40 in: "case when (_years_between(current_date,"

Comment: Updated OP, source database is Oracle

Comment: It works for me.  All I did was substitute a query item of mine into your expression, remove the birthdate after case, and add an end operator.  Check your expression at or about position 40.

Comment: Found out what it was, had to use abs(current_date - [BIRTHDATE]), because... Oracle, apparently :) Somehow _years_between doesn't want to work with the Oracle dateTime format, even when I tried casting the column as date